# Detect MIME-type change on image request nodejs

Tags: node.js, mime-types, http-get

I'm using the requests library in NodeJS to pull images from a website, and save them to disk. The website I'm pulling from, instead of 404-ing, redirects to the homepage, and serves the HTML. Is there a proper way of detecting this change/redirect without parsing the body of the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `Content-Type` sent by the server in `response.headers['content-type']`.